# Is it possible to implement multiple interfaces in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Is it possible to specify a type that implements multiple interfaces within a GraphQL schema? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. As outlined in the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Objects):

> An object type may declare that it implements **one or more** unique interfaces.

Keep in mind that the resulting object must be a "super-set of all interfaces it implements" -- it must implement all the fields each interface has and these fields cannot conflict. For example, if Interface A and Interface B both have a field called `something`, the type of that field must be the same for both interfaces in order for an Object Type to implement both interfaces.

Here's a simple example that you can [open in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymznmymxmx) and play around with.

**Note**: As others have pointed out, using a comma to separate the interfaces is no longer supported -- please use an `&` (ampersand) instead.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    someAnimal: Animal!
    someBird: Bird!
  }

  interface Bird {
    wingspan: Int!
  }

  interface Animal {
    speed: Int!
  }

  type Swallow implements Animal & Bird {
    wingspan: Int!
    speed: Int!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    someAnimal: (root, args, context) => {
      return { wingspan: 7, speed: 24 };
    },
    someBird: (root, args, context) => {
      return { wingspan: 6, speed: 25 };
    }
  },
  Bird: {
    __resolveType: () => "Swallow"
  },
  Animal: {
    __resolveType: () => "Swallow"
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Please note that the spec now also allows [interfaces to implement other interfaces](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Interfaces.Interfaces-Implementing-Interfaces).

> When defining an interface that implements another interface, the implementing interface must define each field that is specified by the implemented interface... Transitively implemented interfaces (interfaces implemented by the interface that is being implemented) must also be defined on an implementing type or interface.

In GraphQL.js, this is supported as of version 15.0.0.

Comment: Per the latest version of the spec (https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Interfaces): "Types may also implement multiple interfaces. For example, `Business` implements both the `NamedEntity` and `ValuedEntity` interfaces in the example [below]." `type Business implements NamedEntity & ValuedEntity {`

Answer (score 16):

It seems comma separating the interfaces doesn't work anymore. I had to use "&" instead to make it work (Apollo), see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521662/1959584

```
type Something implements First & Second
```

Comment: Per the latest version of the spec (https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Interfaces): "Types may also implement multiple interfaces. For example, `Business` implements both the `NamedEntity` and `ValuedEntity` interfaces in the example [below]." `type Business implements NamedEntity & ValuedEntity {`

Answer (score 6):

I think yes, it should be possible as the specification describes on http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Interfaces.

Here is the example.

```
interface NamedEntity {
  name: String
}

interface ValuedEntity {
  value: Int
}

type Person implements NamedEntity {
  name: String
  age: Int
}

type Business implements NamedEntity & ValuedEntity {
  name: String
  value: Int
  employeeCount: Int
}
```

Comment: Per the latest version of the spec (https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Interfaces): "Types may also implement multiple interfaces. For example, `Business` implements both the `NamedEntity` and `ValuedEntity` interfaces in the example [below]." `type Business implements NamedEntity & ValuedEntity {`