# Implement multiple interfaces in graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

I am using the relay compiler and it is not letting me compile a schema with a type that implements multiple interfaces. I made a small test project:

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "relay": "relay-compiler --src ./ --schema schema.graphqls"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-relay": "1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "relay-compiler": "1.5.0"
  }
}
```

schema.graphqls

```
interface First {
    a: String
}

interface Second {
    b: String
}

type Something implements First, Second {
    a: String
    b: String
}
```

test.js

```
import { graphql } from "react-relay";

graphql`fragment Test_item on Something {
    a
    b
}`;
```

If you run this with npm run relay (after npm install) you get the error:

```
Error: Error loading schema. Expected the schema to be a .graphql or a .json
file, describing your GraphQL server's API. Error detail:

GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "Second"
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use an ampersand instead of a comma for multiple interfaces.
See here: http://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Interfaces

```
type Something implements First & Second
```