# GraphQL Union within Union

Tags: graphql, graphql-tag

Below is a query which is conceptually what I'm looking for. But, I cannot figure out how to implement... or even if it's possible.

```
query getMedia($id: ID!) {
  media(id: $id) {
    __typename
    title

    ... on Movie {
      fps
    }

    ... on Music {
      duration

      ... on Song {
        lyrics
      }

      ... on Composition {
        movements
      }
    }

  }
```

Basically, I have types of Media, if it's Music, there are different types of music. If the record is a "Song", I would expect this as a response:

```
{
  "media": {
    "__typename": "Song",
    "duration": 5.67,
    "title": "Some Song",
    "lyrics": "La de da de da de da de day oh",
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, your `media` field as it appears in your question would have to be an Interface, not a Union, since it includes at least one field that's common to all implementing types (`title`). Regardless, whether we're talking about Interfaces or Unions, the kind of syntax you're suggesting is not supported. Only object types can implement Interfaces. [Similarly](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Unions):

> The member types of a Union type must all be Object base types; Scalar, Interface and Union types must not be member types of a Union. Similarly, wrapping types must not be member types of a Union.

`Movie`, `Song` and `Composition` will all need to extend the `Media` interface, and then they can be queries like so:

```
query getMedia($id: ID!) {
  media(id: $id) {
    __typename
    title

    ... on Movie {
      fps
    }

    ... on Song {
      duration
      lyrics
    }

    ... on Composition {
      duration
      movements
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, that does mean some duplication in your inline fragments. The good news is, an object type *can* [implement multiple interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227332/is-it-possible-to-implement-multiple-interfaces-in-graphql/45229099#45229099), and implementing an interface does not preclude it from being included in one or more unions. So, if you need it, you can still create a `Music` interface or union and use that as a return type for a different field.